# C++ multiple definition error when compiling in G++

Tags: c++, g++

I'm running into some issues compiling and I'm not sure why. I get a multiple definition error for a few things, however, as far as I'm aware, I only define them once. I'm confused as to why this is happening and where these definitions are happening and why its not working. I'm not that familiar with C++ so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here and would appreciate some assistance.

make

```
/usr/bin/g++ -c -o object/author.o src/author.cpp -g -I./include
/usr/bin/g++ -o ---- object/connection_manager.o object/author.o.   object/control_header_lib.o object/network_util.o object/main.o     object/control_handler.o -g -I./include 
object/main.o:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `control_socket'
object/connection_manager.o:(.bss+0x104): first defined here
object/main.o: In function `main':
/home/Documents/---/src/main.cpp:9: multiple definition of `router_socket'
object/connection_manager.o:/home/Documents/---/src.   /connection_manager.cpp:35: first defined here
object/main.o: In function `main':
/home/Documents/---/src/main.cpp:9: multiple definition of `data_socket'
object/connection_manager.o:/home/Documents/---/src. /connection_manager.cpp:35: first defined here
object/control_handler.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of  `CONTROL_PORT'
object/main.o:/home/Documents/---/src/main.cpp:9: first defined here
object/connection_manager.o: In function `main_loop()':
/home/Documents/---/src/connection_manager.cpp:33: undefined reference to `new_control_conn(int)'
/home/Documents/---/src/connection_manager.cpp:54: undefined reference to `isControl(int)'
/home/Documents/---/src/connection_manager.cpp:56: undefined reference  to `control_recv_hook(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:19: recipe for target '----' failed
make: *** [----] Error 1
```

main.cpp

```
#include "../include/global.h"
#include "../include/connection_manager.h"

using namespace std;
int sockfd;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc != 2){
        ERROR("Incorrect number of args...\n");
    }
    printf("control port: %d\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    sscanf(argv[1], "%" SCNu16, &CONTROL_PORT);
    init();
    return 0;
}
```

global.h

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H_
#define GLOBAL_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define ERROR(err_msg) {perror(err_msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
#define BUILD_BUG_ON(condition) ((void)sizeof(char[1 - 2*!!(condition)])) 



#endif
```

connection_manager.cpp

```
#include <sys/select.h>
#include "../include/connection_manager.h"
#include "../include/global.h"
#include "../include/control_handler.h"

int control_socket, router_socket, data_socket;

void init()
{
    control_socket = create_control_sock();
}
```

connection_manager.h

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_MANAGER_H_
#define CONNECTION_MANAGER_H_

void init();

#endif
```

control_handler.cpp

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <list>

#include "../include/global.h"
#include "../include/network_util.h"
#include "../include/control_header_lib.h"
#include "../include/author.h"

#ifndef PACKET_USING_STRUCT
    #define CNTRL_CONTROL_CODE_OFFSET 0x04
    #define CNTRL_PAYLOAD_LEN_OFFSET 0x06
#endif

struct ControlConn  // linked list for active control connections
{
    int sockfd;
    // ..
}*connection, *conn_temp;

std::list<ControlConn> control_conn_list;

int create_control_sock()
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in control_addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(control_addr);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock < 0){
        ERROR("Failed to create socket...\n");
    }

    bzero(&control_addr, addrlen);
    control_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    control_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    control_addr.sin_port = htons(CONTROL_PORT);

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&control_addr, addrlen) < 0){
        ERROR("Bind failed...");
    }

    if (listen(sock, 5) < 0){
        ERROR("Listen failed...");
    }

    return sock;
}
```

control_handler.h

```
#ifndef CONTROL_HANDLER_H_
#define CONTROL_HANDLER_H_

int create_control_sock();
int new_control_conn(int sock_index);
bool isControl(int sock_index);
bool control_recv_hook(int sock_index);

#endif
```

Comment: In your header file, plainly: `int control_socket, router_socket, data_socket;` -- this defines these symbols ***in every .cpp file that includes this header file***. After all, that's what `#include`-ing means: include this as if it appears in the file itself. Find every one of your `.cpp`'s that includes this header file. You've just defined these symbols, in each such file. So, what exactly is your question about these multiple definitions?

Comment: Even when I move it out of the header file, I get an identical error.           *** updated original post with this

Comment: No, you cannot "get an identical error", since, in this case, the `.cpp` files that reference the symbols would now get a different error. After editing your question, the end result is that the question now contains fake code, instead of real code, since the shown code does not match the shown error messages.

Comment: I think you can strip this down to a much smaller [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In header file you need to just declare variable:

```
extern uint16_t CONTROL_PORT;
```

Then in corresponding cpp (`global.cpp`) file you should define it:

```
uint16_t CONTROL_PORT;
```

Comment: You said that it had worked for you. And now you unaccept the answer and remove the comment. Need help?

Comment: Yes I got a little ahead of myself and it turned out that the error only went away because of another one. When I found and corrected it, the same original error returned. I've updated the original post. Thanks for checking back in. I appreciate it. For the record, this started out as C code (which worked) and I need to convert it, so it most likely has something to do with part of the code getting lost in translation.

Comment: Never mind. Just realized I didnt define it in main. Thank you so much for your help.